# Writing updating query only if sufficient balance is available

Tags: sql

I have this requirement, where I need to update the balance of an account once a purchase is made. Sometimes, the balance is not sufficient. So, I want to update only if the balance is sufficient to make the purchase. How to write the right sql for this

I need something like

```
Update account set balance = balance - amount only if balance >= amount.
```

How can I write something like this in sql.

Comment: I'm assuming you also have something like `WHERE account_id = ?`.  And do you need to return a result (to another query, or client) stating whether the update has happened or not?  And in what variety of SQL?  Are you on MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, TeraData, PostGreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the WHERE keyword. It lets you filter a command to a subset of the table. Example:

```
Update account
SET balance = balance - amount
WHERE balance >= amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` expression like so:

```
Update account 
SET balance = CASE 
                WHEN balance >= amount THEN balance - amount 
                ELSE balance 
              END;
```

Comment: Why even bother updating the row, if it doesn't have enough of a balance?  This method has the potential for more errors then a simple where clause.